# How to setup google identity provider with fastapi using cognito, I have done required setup with aws and google developer console

Tags: reactjs, boto3, amazon-cognito, fastapi, google-identity

It's really confusing to use google identity data to create user at the AWS cognito end. The process of using cognito boto3 client for google identity is confusing in a sense. There is no clear explanation in documentation of it.

What I want to do:

I can decode the jwt data provided from the google cloud backend but can't really figure out how to assign the sub as it's not declared as a field. I think there must be a better way to assign users to google group and do it altogether.

Please provide some sample code for signup and signin using google idp and boto3 to save user in the cognito userpool.